# Querying multiple meta_keys in Wordpress SQL query

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

Here's my Query... I'm looking to narrow this query down to users of one specific role ("meta_key = 'wp_capabilities' AND meta_value = 'employee'")...how do I add that additional conditional to this string?

```
$get_users = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users
WHERE ID = ANY (
SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta
WHERE meta_key = '$meta_key'
AND meta_value LIKE '%$search%'
) ORDER BY user_nicename ASC LIMIT 10000";
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you can add additional explanation after {AND meta_value LIKE '%$search%'} this line

Comment: Why don't you just use either `get_users()` or the `WP_User_Query` class? You can query by multiple [meta field values](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and you can specify a [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#User_Role_Parameter) to search for.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov with that I can't query for partial matches. At least I haven't found that I can...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean. With the `meta_query` you can still use `LIKE` as a comparator. Am I misunderstanding you? So your above query would look something like `$users = get_users( array( 'role' => 'employee', 'orderby' => 'nicename', 'meta_query' => array( array( 'key' => $meta_key, 'value' => $search, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ) ), ) );`

Comment: Nope! That is perfect! I definitely missed that in my searches. Thanks @NikolaIvanovNikolov!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT u.ID, u.user_login
FROM wp_users u, wp_usermeta m
WHERE u.ID = m.user_id 
AND m.meta_key LIKE 'wp_capabilities'
AND m.meta_value LIKE '%employee%'
```

Comment: Please provide a description for your code snippet. Also be careful because the syntax was broken.